# Decrypting Text Using AES in CBC Mode

Tags: php, encryption, aes, mcrypt

I have this code

```
$td = \mcrypt_module_open(\MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
            \mcrypt_generic_init($td, '12345678901234561234567890123456', '12345678901234567890123456789012');
            echo mdecrypt_generic(
                    $td,
                    \mcrypt_generic($td, "Testing")
            );
```

But the result is **ˆ]Ië{ŒÕÌe}Q™‡ÿòø¬ÀÿÙ®»/›**
Why isnt the text being properly decrypted?  I also tried base_64 encoding and decoding in the right places so i think the problem might be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reinitialize before decryption, i.e. call crypt_generic_init again.
Also, after encryption is finished, you should call mcrypt_generic_deinit.

Comment: That's how symmetric ciphers work in CBC mode - they continuosly changes IV, so at the beginning of decryption it needs to be initialized again. Also, you should note that in normal circumstances encryption, followed by the decryption of the same data, will never happen ;)

Comment: I see.  And yes I agree, this code was just the simplest form, not a real implementation.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a wild guess, but since you're using CBC mode, you probably need to reset the iv before you can decrypt it.

```
$td = \mcrypt_module_open(\MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
$key = '12345678901234561234567890123456';
$iv =  '12345678901234567890123456789012';

\mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$encrypted = \mcrypt_generic($td, "Testing");

\mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
echo \mdecrypt_generic($td, $encrypted);
```